# Debian keymap changing with qEmu?

Tags: debian, qemu, keyboard

Here's the context : I have a Debian 7.3 as the host system (with **LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8**), on which I'm running virtual machines with qEmu (for educational purpose only).
I've created a disk image on which I've installed a Debian 7.3 testing.

NB : I've set the guest system language to english but the keyboard to the french layout.
NB2 : There's no X on the guest system. Actually, there's just the base system.

When booting this machine with default options : *qemu -hda debian.img* (under X from the host system), a new window opens, I can see Debian booting and everything works fine : I can log in and the keyboard layout matches my physical keyboard : "AZERTY".

But, if I start the guest system in a no-X environment (qemu -hda debian.img -curses), once booted, the keymap appears to be something weird :
- pressing "azerty" displays "qwerty"
- pressing "1" displays "7"

Do you have any idea what's going on ? How may I fix this ?

Comment: Write up your solution as an actual answer and then mark it as accepted. That the approp. way to show that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of RTFM, I found the **-k** option (ooops). It works just fine with : *qemu -hda debian.img -curses -k fr*

Hope this may help others ...